# Problems with USB mouse on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, usb, mouse

My mouse stops working after a few seconds, or a few minutes at most. It works fine on my Raspberry Pi and on my Mac, but my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system complains:

```
[  654.508063] usb 2-5: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
[  654.712876] usb 2-5: device descriptor read/all, error -71
```

When I unplug and re-plug the mouse, it will work for some more seconds. This is obviously not a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be the mouse anyway? Low speed device seems to point to a USB 1.1 mouse. Maybe a new mouse might work better? The board is an ASUS M2N with AMD Athlon X2.

Comment: tried using a different USB-port (and/or an external and externally-powered USB hub) - for testing purposes..?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a problem with the USB suspend power-saving feature.

If you have powernap installed, this might help:

```
sudo powernap-action --disable usb_autosuspend
```

Without powernap, you could try disabling the autosuspend feature in the usbcore module:

```
echo "options usbcore autosuspend=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/usbcore
```

You'll probably have to reboot (or unload and re-load the module, but good luck with that if you're using a USB keyboard) to see if the change is effective.

If it doesn't help, do the following to clean up:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/usbcore
```